# Kotlin Generics Type Mismatch

Tags: kotlin, generics, type-inference

```
    fun <R, F : Function<R>?, K : KFunction<R>?> Array<F>.reflect(): Array<K> = this.map<F, K> { it?.reflect<R>() }.toTypedArray()
```

*Compile-time error inside `map`'s lambda*

> Type mismatch: inferred type is `KFunction<R>?` but `K` was expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The source of confusion on my part is that why `KFunction<R>?` is not `K` if `K` is defined to be any subtype of `KFunction<R>`?

As you said `K` is a subtype of `KFunction<R>`, but `Function<R>.reflect()` does not return `K`, it returns `KFunction<R>` where a value of type `K` is expected. Consider this example:

```
class A : KFunction<String> {
    // ...implements all methods of KFunction<String>
}

arrayOf({ "foo" }).reflect<String, () -> String, A>()
```

- `R` is `String`
- `F` is `Function<String>`
- `K` is `A`, a class which extends `KFunction<String>`

Now to satisfy the function, the `it?.reflect<R>()` part should return a value of type `A`, but it returns `KFunction<String>` instead.

Perhaps you declared too many type parameters for what you want to achieve? What about this function:

```
fun <R> Array<out Function<R>?>.reflect(): Array<KFunction<R>?> =
        this.map { it?.reflect<R>() }.toTypedArray()
```

Leave a comment if you have any question.

Comment: (1) The function exists (https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-function.html)
(2) The source of confusion on my part is that why `KFunction<R>?` is not `K` if `K` is defined to be any subtype of `KFunction<R>?`
(Note) I am not asking this question because i don't know what causes the compile-time error. I am asking because I am confused as to why this is the case.